# Can numbers of form $n^2 + 1$ have prime factors of form $4m + 3$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I'm reading this [paper](https://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1959-13-066/S0025-5718-1959-0105784-2/) and I think that the author uses the fact that numbers of form $n^2 + 1$ have only prime factors of form $4m + 1$ (excluding the case when $n$ is odd so $2$ is also a possible prime factor). Why is this so?

As I can see, if $n$ is even then $n^2 + 1 \equiv 1\ (\textrm{mod}\ 4)$ and as long as there is even number of prime factors of form $4m + 3$ that won't be violated.

Comment: [$a(n)=4n^2+1:$ oeis/A053755](https://oeis.org/A053755).  The result you refer to was partially proven by Cino Hilliard in 2006 and the proof was corrected by Franklin T. Adams-Watters in 2011.  I don't spot how to prove it at a glance and would probably need to find the original paper.

Comment: @JMoravitz Those are the names of the people discussing the result on OEIS. The result was proven by Gauss and is known as quadratic reciprocity.

Comment: @JMoravitz Please be much more careful with duplicate claims. I reopened it.

Comment: @BillDubuque I still do not see the difference between the two.  In this question they ask why odd numbers of the form $n^2+1$ (*i.e. occurs when $n$ is even, so for $n=2x$ is of the form $4x^2+1$*) only has prime factors of the form $4m+1$ and none in the form $4m+3$.  In the post I marked as duplicate it asks why numbers of the form $4x^2+1$ (*i.e. odd numbers of the form $n^2+1$*) factors only into primes of the form $4y+1$.  They seem like identical questions to me, just using $n$'s and $m$'s rather than $x$'s and $y$'s.

Comment: @BillDubuque if you are convinced the post I marked as duplicate was done so incorrectly, then please tell me why you think that.  Otherwise I will surely make the same "mistake" again in the future.

Comment: @JMoravitz  As you can see above, there are prior questions wtth much simpler answers that apply *immediately*.

Comment: @BillDubuque So you are saying that I was not wrong that the post I linked was a duplicate, you are just saying that there were better candidates.  This was not made clear in your original comment.